# Hadoop Hangs on Job Kill Command

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running Hive 0.12 on a Hadoop 1.0.3 cluster and a Job got stuck at 2.5% in the mapping phase with many of the tasks showing a 'Lost task tracker' error.

When I attempt to run the hadoop job -kill job_id command, the command simply hangs and the job is not killed.

In addition, running any of the other hadoop job commands hang as well (such as hadoop job -list). The hadoop fs commands seem to work just fine.

I checked the log files, and I could not find anything out of the ordinary other than the notifications of the lost tasks.

Currently the cluster is stuck on this job and I need to run other MapReduce jobs. What is the best way to kill this job if the hadoop job -kill command is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no error messages when executing the command ?

To stop the job, you can try to restart hive or restart your mapreduce service on hadoop.